# Why can't I change variables?

Tags: html, arrays, function

I cannot seem to make currentCost[0] or buildingA increase at all in my code.

My problem is probably in here:

```
{
    document.getElementById("costA").innerHTML = currentCost[0]
    document.getElementById("amountA").innerHTML = buildingA
    document.getElementById("canPay").innerHTML = "You just bought another!"
    count.postMessage({action:'subtract', amount:currentCost[0], once:true});
    currentCost[0] = Math.ceiling(nlogn(currentCost[0]+1)) + 5
    buildingA = buildingA + 1
}
```

This is inside an if statement.

My goal is to make it so when the building is bought, it adds one to the amount of buildings of that type that exist, plus increase the price according to a predetermined function, namely `newPrice = oldPrice*log10(oldPrice)`.

However, when I buy building A, the price will remain at 15, and it always says I have 0 buildingA's.

Comment: You should post your source code here, not a link to your entire repository. Code postings here should be [MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in your code there is a line `var nlogn = nlogn();` which make `nlogn` is a variable so it gives `TypeError: nlogn is not a function`.
Change the variable name.

And put scripts at the end of `<body>`.

Full Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test incremental</title>

</head>

<body>
Your money: <output id="result"></output><br><br>

<button onclick="buyA();">Buy Building A</button><br>
Cost of next one: <output id="costA"></output><br>
<output id="canPay"></output><br>
You own <output id="amountA"></output> Building A's!

<script language="JavaScript">

var buyCost = 0;
var buyable = true;
var count;
var buildingModifier = 0;
var cost = 0;
var currentCost = [15, 25, 50, 100]
var money = 0;
//var nlogn = nlogn();

var buildingA = 0;

function beginGame() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(count) == "undefined") {
            count = new Worker("counterWorker.js");
        }
        count.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
            money = event.data
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
    }
}

function nlogn(n) {
    return n * Math.log10(n);
}

function checkBuyable() {
    if(cost < money) {
        buyable = true;
    } else {
        buyable = false;
    }
}

var costA = document.createElement("costA")
var canPay = document.createElement("canPay")
var amountA = document.createElement("amountA")

function buyA() {
    cost = currentCost[0];
    checkBuyable();
    if (buyable == true) {
        document.getElementById("costA").innerHTML = currentCost[0]
        document.getElementById("amountA").innerHTML = buildingA
        document.getElementById("canPay").innerHTML = "You just bought another!"
        count.postMessage({action:'subtract', amount:currentCost[0], once:true});
        currentCost[0] = Math.ceil(nlogn(currentCost[0]+1)) + 5
        buildingA = buildingA + 1
        setTimeout(resetCanPay, 1000)
    } else {
        document.getElementById("canPay").innerHTML = "Too Expensive to buy another!"
        setTimeout(resetCanPay, 1000)
    }
    document.getElementById("costA").innerHTML = currentCost[0]
}

function resetCanPay() {
    document.getElementById("canPay").innerHTML = " "
}

currentCost[0] = Math.ceil(nlogn(currentCost[0]+1))
document.getElementById("costA").innerHTML = currentCost[0]

beginGame();

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Hm, that still doesn't work. I can still buy the building for 15, it doesn't make me wait until over 20.

Comment: I declared nlogn in my entire code already. That's not the problem. Edit: oh, that was the problem. I thought it could tell between a variable and a function.

Comment: Edited again. please check.